# How do you write a method that prints objects in a array in java?

Tags: java, arrays

How do you print objects in a array in java?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simplest way to print an array in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/simplest-way-to-print-an-array-in-java)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several useful [`toString()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) and [`deepToString()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) methods in [`java.util.Arrays`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) class.

```
String[] strings = { "foo", "bar", "waa" };
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strings)); // [foo, bar, waa]
```

An alternative is to just [loop](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) over them yourself and print each item separately.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/):

```
org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.join(Arrays.asList(strings), ", ");
```

Using [Spring](http://www.springsource.org/about) Core:

```
org.springframework.util.StringUtils.collectionToDelimitedString(Arrays.asList(strings), ", ");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `for` loop.

Here's example :

```
  String[] colors = {"red","blue","black","green","yellow"};
  for (String color : colors) {
   System.out.println(color);
  }
```

Also check : [What's the simplest way to print a Java array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/simplest-way-to-print-an-array-in-java)

As quoted by Esko in above link is best answer:

> In Java 5 **Arrays.toString(arr)** or
>   **Arrays.deepToString(arr)** for arrays
>   within arrays.
>
> Note that Object[]
>   version calls **.toString()** of each
>   object in array. If my memory serves
>   me correct, the output is even
>   decorated in the exact way you're
>   asking.